# Is "more full picture" an absolute phrase?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis, comparatives, modifiers, absolute-constructions

In the following example, is *more full picture* a kind of absolute phrase?

> He has given us a lot, *more full picture* of dinosaurs of the East Coast.

Comment: It would more commonly be *fuller* rather than *more full*. These mean the same thing, but *more full* is quite rare. [See Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fuller%2C+more+full&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma between "a lot" and "more"?

Comment: I wouldn't put a comma there but you do see people do funny things with commas and adjectives/adverbs, having recently searched on here for *comma adjective*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's a comparative phrase. It implies that previous "pictures of dinosaurs of the East Coast" were not as full as this new picture, and that even this new picture is not a complete picture. There are still gaps that need filling in.

Rather than "a more full picture", "a more **complete** picture" is probably better. But the sentence you offer is ungrammatical:

> He has given us a lot: a more complete picture of dinosaurs of the East Coast.

or

> He has given us a more complete picture of dinosaurs of the East Coast.

or

> He has given us a picture of dinosaurs of the East Coast that is a lot more complete.

all are grammatical and mean the same thing. Which is best is your choice. There may be some other sentence that you prefer, however. These aren't the only ways to say what you want to say.

Comment: More complete than previous treatments of East-Coast dinosaurs, his treatise is commendable.